# How to calculate perimeter using the area and the perimeter of a smaller area

Tags: problem-solving

[image]

I have having trouble understanding how to break this problem apart.

I have an $ L$ shape with a rectangle in it.

The smaller rectangle has a side of $5 m$ and a side of $7 m$, the $L$ shape has an area of $6.25m^2$

I can work out the total area for both but not how to use the area to calculate the perimeter of the $L$ shape when no sides length or width are know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so my mate Ryan showed me the way.

$A=lw$

$A=(5+w)(7+w)$
$A=(5+x)(7+x)$
$A=5*7+x*7+5*x+x*x$
$A=35+7x+5x+x^2$
$A=x^2+12x+35=41.25m^2$
That is the total area 
$A_F = A_T - A_S = 41.25 - 35 = 6.25$  
$A=x_2+12x=6.25$
$A=x_2+12x-6.25=0$ Plug that into a grapher x = 0.5m
That gives me the sides and the question is answered.

Thanks for all the help from everyone it was more me not being able to express my question properly

Answer (score 1):

The geometric problem is not fully specified.  We assume that the vertical and horizontal arms of the L have the same thickness $d$. (We were not told that the thicknesses are the same.) We suppose also that the $5\times 7$ rectangle referred to is the rectangle embraced by the two arms of the L, but *outside* the L.

Then if we draw the L shape, the little $d \times d$ square in the lower left corner has area $d^2$, and the rest of the L has area $d(5+7)$. So we obtain the equation
$$d^2+12d=6.25.$$
Rewrite as $d^2+12d-6.25=0$, and solve. The positive root is $1/2$.

Now the perimeter of the L is easy to find.  It is $2(7) +2(5)+4(1/2)$.

**Remark:** Is the above the right interpretation? That is certainly not clear. But the happy fact that the discriminant $(12)^2-(4)(-6.25)$ is a perfect square is evidence of sorts that the interpretation might be the intended one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a lack of informations .

Let's denote perimeter of the shape as $P$ and total area as $A$ .

$A=(x+5)(y+7)-5\cdot 7$ (see picture below)

$P=2x+2y+24$

therefore , we have following  two equations  :

$\begin{cases}
 A=xy+7x+5y \\
 P=2x+2y+24
\end{cases}$

hence , you cannot calculate value of perimeter exactly .

[image]

Comment: added a graphic to better describe my problem

Comment: It is a question given by my Instructor, I assume that it is solvable. But I am not sure how to attack it at all